# c# Image resizing adding extra pixels

Tags: c#, image, resize

The following code behaves very oddly. It adds some extra spacing at the bottom of the image, and I can not see why. Result of code:

[image]

And this is the code that I am working with:

```
    public static Image ReDraw(this Image main, int w, int h,
        CompositingQuality quality = CompositingQuality.Default, //linear?
        SmoothingMode smoothing_mode = SmoothingMode.None,
        InterpolationMode ip_mode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor)
    {
        //size
        double dbl = (double)main.Width / (double)main.Height;

        //preserve size ratio
        if ((int)((double)h * dbl) <= w)
            w = (int)((double)h * dbl);
        else
            h = (int)((double)w / dbl);

        //draw
        Image newImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(w, h);
        Graphics thumbGraph = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
        thumbGraph.CompositingQuality = quality;
        thumbGraph.SmoothingMode = smoothing_mode;
        thumbGraph.InterpolationMode = ip_mode;
        thumbGraph.Clear(Color.Transparent);
        thumbGraph.DrawImage(main, 0, 0, w, h);

        thumbGraph.DrawImage(main,
        new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, w, h),
        new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, main.Width, main.Height),
        System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        return newImage;
    }
```

Comment: Try some existing libraries?

Comment: Not an option, this seems far too simple to start adding libraries to a portable app

Comment: You are **Reinventing the wheel**?

Comment: Check the values of w and h after the ratio calculation, that can be a rounding problem, try with Math.Floor. Also, post some example data, that would help a lot to find the problem.

Comment: Your example bitmap makes it look like you are not actually resizing the image in your test. If that's the case, and assuming the image is 116x124 as you show here, I don't see any way for the bitmap to wind up larger; the `h` and `w` values will be calculated to be exactly the same (i.e. `116` and `124`), and so regardless of what inaccuracies might result from the `DrawImage()` call, the actual `Bitmap` object will still have to have the correct number of pixels.

Comment: Please fix your question so that it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem you're concerned with. Explain in detail what you've tried to correct the problem, and what _specifically_ you are having trouble with. Make sure you explain what is different about your question as compared to the several others on Stack Overflow asking about artifacts when resizing bitmaps.

Comment: use nicer variable names and then make sure you get the params for DrawImage right!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thumbGraph.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

Comment: If you want to add this as an answer, explain why this should work, that info thrown like this is not useful for SO, that's why someone downvoted you.